# How to reinstall Python 2.7 on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, python

I wanted to install Python 3.7.2 on my MacBook Pro (2015) running Mojave and it would not install correctly and in attempt to trash the incorrect install I trashed the installed Python 2.7 version.

How do I reinstall Python 2.7 to correct my mistake and where to I go to make the correction? New to programming so very limited knowledge, now nothing works.

Comment: Can't you just reinstall v2.7?

Comment: @fixer1234 Not if it’s core macOS. The best remedy is to reinstall macOS on top of the current install. That should not destroy any currently set files, applications and settings but basically just overwrites all of the core macOS system stuff which *should* repair things.

Comment: The problem is xcode uses a specific macOS shipped version of Python 2.7. And this is used specifically by Xcode for debugging. Other tools like chisel released by facebook also require this macOS specific version. Downloading from python.org does not work to my knowledge. Way to test? Run import lldb and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

Mac comes with Python 2.7 by default. So did you mean that you downloaded Python 2 from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) and deleted it, or that you uninstalled Python 2.7?

If you just downloaded the installer and deleted it, that shouldn't be a problem. Since Mac comes with Python 2 by default, if you haven't gotten rid of it, you should be able to open up a terminal and type in `python` to get a Python 2 prompt.

If you somehow uninstalled Python 2.7, then you can download a new copy of Python 2.7 from [this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2715/). (You probably want the "macOS 64-bit installer"). Download it and install it (I think the built-in app Installer can open it) and you should have Python 2 back again.

If you have some other issue (I'm not sure what you mean by "now nothing works") please specify in a comment, with the error messages if there are any, and I'll edit this answer.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Python2 and Python3 are not interdependent, so it doesn't matter if Python2 doesn't work. Also, there's essentially zero reasons to be using Python2 in 2020, *especially* for learning. Just fix the Python3 installation: https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/